# What's the best way to include nested objects of derived types in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I need to include nested objects in an entity. The problem is that also need nested objects that are nested in the nested objects and on top of it these second level nested objects are of different types. I will show an example of something similar to my case, don't worry whether the schema makes sense to you, I'm just trying to give an easier example. So:

```
public class Garage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Vehicle<TDriver, TMechanic>
    where TDriver : Driver
    where TMechanic : Mechanic
{
    public virtual ICollection<TDriver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TMechanic> Mechanics { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle<CarDriver, CarMechanic>
{
    // Some properties
}

public class Truck : Vehicle<TruckDriver, TruckMechanic>
{
    // Some properties
}

public abstract class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GarageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Garage Garage { get; set; }
}

public class CarDriver : Driver
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class TruckDriver : Driver
{
    public int TruckId { get; set; }
    public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Mechanic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CarMechanic : Mechanic
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class TruckMechanic : Mechanic
{
    public int TruckId { get; set; }
    public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that for some reason a Driver can have either a Car or a Truck and that's the reason for this class structure.

So, now, when I create a new Garage entity and create new Drivers in it I provide just the Ids of their Car or Truck entities. After the new Garage entity with its nested Driver entities is created, everything is okay, except for the fact that the Driver entities (CarDriver or TruckDriver) have just their CarId and TruckId fields loaded. The thing is that I need also the real Car and Truck entities. So, how can I include them?

The following line doesn't do the work.

```
context.Garages.Include(g => g.Drivers)
```

The only thing that I came up with (and I know that it's the stupidest thing that I can do) is to create a new instance of the DbContext object and get the Garage entity by Id.

Does anybody know how to cope with this situation without doing this stupid workaround?

**Edit:**
I added Vehicle, Mechanic, CarMechanic and TruckMechanic classes so that my example can be more similar to my real code. Now, from this example it doesn't make a lot of sense for a Car object to be a Vehicle of CarDrivers and CarMechanics. But in my case it's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say that for some reason a Driver can have either a Car or a
>   Truck and that's the reason for this class structure.
>
> ...
>
> The thing is that I need also the real Car and Truck entities. So, how
>   can I include them?

You seem to want to be able to access each driver's vehicle in a Polymorphic way. But apparently, you didn't expose such a vehicle on the base `Driver` class, and since you're accessing your data using `Garage.Drivers` (which is using that base `Driver` class), you're ending up with the problem of inaccessible vehicle.

Now, in an ideal world you would simply do:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle { public string CarSpecificProperty { get; set; } }
public class Truck : Vehicle { public string TruckSpecificProperty { get; set; } }

public abstract class Driver<TVehicle> where TVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public virtual TVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class CarDriver : Driver<Car> {}
public class TruckDriver : Driver<Truck> {}
```

The problem is that Entity Framework will refuse to map open generic Entities and you won't be able to create the appropriate `DbSet<Driver<?>>` in your context.

That will require us to come up with a less-cleaner approach:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle { public string CarSpecificProperty { get; set; } }
public class Truck : Vehicle { public string TruckSpecificProperty { get; set; } }

public abstract class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class CarDriver : Driver
{
    public Car Car
    {
        get { return this.Vehicle as Car; }
        set { this.Vehicle = value as Car; }
    }
}

public class TruckDriver : Driver
{
    public Truck Truck
    {
        get { return this.Vehicle as Truck; }
        set { this.Vehicle = value as Truck; }
    }
}
```

And in your `DbContext`:

```
public IDbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CarDriver>().Ignore(x => x.Car);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TruckDriver>().Ignore(x => x.Truck);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And the actual usage would be:

```
var driversWithVehicles = context.Drivers.Where(x => x.Vehicle != null);
var driversWithToyotaVehicles = context.Drivers.Where(x => x.Vehicle.Make == "Toyota");

var carDrivers = context.Drivers.OfType<CarDriver>();
var carDriversWithCriteria = context.Drivers.OfType<CarDriver>().Where(x => (x.Vehicle as Car).CarSpecificProperty == "SomeValue");

var truckDrivers = context.Drivers.OfType<TruckDriver>();
var truckDriversWithCriteria = context.Drivers.OfType<TruckDriver>().Where(x => (x.Vehicle as Truck).TruckSpecificProperty == "SomeValue");
```

(Notice that we don't access `Car/Truck` specific data using the `.Car/.Truck` property, since they are ignored on-purpose and EF will throw when trying to access them)

Now, to address the last piece which is your original `Garage` with `Include` problem:

```
context.Garages.Include(g => g.Drivers.Select(d => d.Vehicle));
```

Or

```
context.Garages.Include("Drivers.Vehicle");
```

Of course, you can now also query those `Drivers` data directly:

```
var allGaragesWithCars = context.Garages.Where(g => g.Drivers.OfType<CarDriver>().Any());
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer. By the way, as I said, this is only an example but if we continue with it, I have to say that I already have a Vehicle class but it is a generic type like: Vehicle<TDriver> where TDriver : Driver and that's why Car class looks like Car : Vehicle<CarDriver>. Of course this doesn't make sense (a Car to be a vehicle with a CarDriver) but in my mini-world it's relevant. Sorry that I didn't mention that from the beginning but didn't think that it should be known from the beginning and didn't expect that someone will dig so deep into the problem.

Comment: @Yulian, I didn't quite understand where your current `Vehicle` fits it. Please update your question and I will try to update the answer accordingly.